# Is there a way to trigger 2 tasks, await for one to complete (without cancelling the other task) and then set a time before returning result

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, timeout

I am implementing a new feature in already existing application and would like to know how best I can achieve the following:

1. Create two tasks.
2. Start them in parallel.
3. Await and wait for one of them to complete.
4. Once one of them completes, spun a timer for t seconds before returning the response. This is done because one of the task might run for a longer time than another.

I have the solution of #1 to #3 but #4.

```cs
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>(length);
tasks.Add(CreateTask(get_data_source));
await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
```

I don't want to provide any timeout in #3. But I would like to wait till the completion of a task and then trigger a timer for t seconds. After t seconds, return the result (if both completed, then both else just the completed task).

Comment: `await Task.Delay(...)`?

Comment: not really clear about what you exactly want. If both tasks finish at the same time, then just return both results ?=! and if 1 of them finishes earlier then wait a whil before returnin the response?

Comment: do you have any means to know which task will finish first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After first task complete, you can await for any of remaining tasks or delay task to complete .

This will give you possibility to await 5 seconds for other tasks to complete, if not, then return result.

```
var tasks = new List<Task>
{
    CreateTask(get_data_source),
    CreateTask(get_data_source2)
};

var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);

await Task.WhenAny(Task.WhenAll(tasks), Task.Delay(5000));

// Return result
```

Comment: im going to up vote, as i think this is the most succinct answer

Comment: I used so ofter WhenAll, that I entirely forgot about WhenAny. This answer makes also my comment obsolete :D definetly worth an upvote

Comment: The `notCompletedTasks` sequence is redundant. You can just await for all `tasks` again. There is nothing wrong with awaiting completed tasks.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, right, because we use `Task.WhenAll` for all tasks, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good place for Task.WhenAll(). It will return when all of the tasks are completed. That way you can just wait for all of the tasks to respond instead of just waiting for an amount of time.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

Another example, using a [`CancellationToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=netframework-4.8) and [`CancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancelafter?view=netframework-4.8)

```
var ts = new CancellationTokenSource();

var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 4)
                     .Select(x => DoStuff(ts.Token))
                     .ToList();

await Task.WhenAny(list);

ts.CancelAfter(1000);

await Task.WhenAll(list);
```

This will help if your *tasks* are using `CancellationTokens` to help shut them down *gracefully*

Comment: I afraid OP doesn't want to cancel longer running task, but just ignore their results.

Comment: @Fabio yeah you are probably right, maybe ill leave this for any other future readers. thanks